# Why do the registers not match the instructions?

Tags: kernel, cpu, bochs

I used bochs's debug feature to check the registers after each instruction. But I found the registers didn't match the instructions.y
    mov sp, 0100h
the sp register was still 0.

```
mov ds, ax
```

the ax register changed to 0
But the application went right. Why?